# How can I use countif to return only a count if sum is > 0 but only count it once

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As you can see I wish to count how many days each product has been shorted.  The amount shorted is not relevant just the amount of days shorted. Salad saw two days shorted, cheese saw no days and Trifle saw 1 day with shorts.  I just can't work out the formula to put into column "I" to automatically calculate days shorted.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cell `I1`, use the following formula, then copy it down:

```
=SUM(--(SUMIFS($D$2:$D$25, $A$2:$A$25, H1, $B$2:$B$25, UNIQUE($B$2:$B$25))>0))
```

**OR**, to make it spill down automatically, use:

```
=BYROW(H1:H3, LAMBDA(r,
SUM(--(SUMIFS(D2:D25, A2:A25, r, B2:B25, UNIQUE(B2:B25))>0))))
```

**OR**, if cell `H1` is already dynamic with `=UNIQUE(A2:A25)`, then use:

```
=BYROW(H1#, LAMBDA(r,
SUM(--(SUMIFS(D2:D25, A2:A25, r, B2:B25, UNIQUE(B2:B25))>0))))
```

**OR**, to include everything in one array, use:

```
=LET(
list, UNIQUE(A2:A25),
HSTACK(list, BYROW(list, LAMBDA(r,
   SUM(--(SUMIFS(D2:D25, A2:A25, r, B2:B25, UNIQUE(B2:B25))>0))))))
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Put this formula in I1 and press CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER (array formula)

```
=SUM(IF(UNIQUE(IF(IF(A$2:A$25=$H1,1,0)*D$2:D$25>0,B$2:B$25,0))>0,1,0))
```

Drag to the end of column H, where the Product names are.

Comment: If the user has UNIQUE then they have Dynamic Arrays and no longer need Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: This does work without the need or CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using MMULT (twice) you could spill it in one go:

```
=LET(u,UNIQUE(A2:B25),
     p,TAKE(u,,1),
     m,MMULT((TOROW(A2:A25)=p)*(TOROW(B2:B25)=INDEX(u,,2)),N(D2:D25>0)),
     q,UNIQUE(p),
HSTACK(q,MMULT(N(TOROW(p)=q),N(m>0))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=LET(
    data, A2:D25,
    p, CHOOSECOLS(data, 1),
    d, CHOOSECOLS(data, 2),
    s, CHOOSECOLS(data, 4),
    one, MAP(
        UNIQUE(p),
        LAMBDA(m, IFERROR(ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(d, (p = m) * s))), 0))),
    two, HSTACK(UNIQUE(p), one),
    two
)
```

[image]